# Why can (++) be used both to prepend and append using map?

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm currently getting started with Haskell (reading Learn Yourself a Haskell),
and came across lines akin to the following:

```hs
map (++"!") ["a", "b"] -- ["a!", "b!"]
map ("!"++) ["a", "b"] -- ["!a", "!b"]
```

Why is this possible, or how does it work? I can't manage to do the same with other non-commutative operations, like division:

```hs
map (3/) [1..3]   -- [3.0,1.5,1.0]
map ((/)3) [1..3] -- [3.0,1.5,1.0]
map (3(/)) [1..3] -- error
```

I feel like I'm missing something here, but the implementation of `map` doesn't give me any hints.

Comment: Change `"!"` into `3` and `++` into `/` and you will see that it does work if you do it correctly and don't sprinkle arbitrary parentheses.

Comment: Going back I now noticed that I did miss something, [Chapter 6.1 of LYAHFGG](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions) briefly mentions sections and the fact that they can be applied in both directions. Shame on me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code is not valid:

```
map (3(/)) [1..3]
```

`(/)` is prefix function but you use it as infix. Compiler see it as you try to function `3` (a function without arguments), add `(/)` as an argument.

`/` is infix function. So, you can do next:

```
map ( / 3) [1..3]   -- [0.3333333333333333,0.6666666666666666,1.0]
map (3 / ) [1..3]   -- [3.0,1.5,1.0]
```

Comment: Seems like I forgot to try a combination without parentheses... Thanks!

Am I correct if I took from this that infix functions can be partially applied from both sides? Is this some kind of syntax magic?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. And yes, it is some kind of syntax magic called [sections](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator).

Answer (score 4):

This is not at all related to map; map’s argument can just be any function.

To understand the functions that you have passed, look at this GHCi session:

```
Prelude> :t (++"!")
(++"!") :: [Char] -> [Char]
Prelude> (++"!") "Hello"
"Hello!"
Prelude> ("!"++) "Hello"
"!Hello"
Prelude> :t ("!"++)
("!"++) :: [Char] -> [Char]
```

What is happening here is the syntactic idea of operation sections ([Haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html), Sec. 3.4), which can be read as

```
(x •) == (\y. x • y)
(• x) == (\y. y • x)
```

where `•` can be any operation like `++`, `*` or even funny self-defined operators like `^_^`.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is declared in brackets: (++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a], it can be used with and without them. If used without brackets, they must appear between the arguments: `"!" ++ "?"`, but with the brackets they are just like normal functions: `(++) "!" "?"`.

Haskell permits "partial application" of functions, so `("!"++)` is the same as `(++) "!"` or `\x -> (++) "!" x`, and `(++"?")` is the same as `\x -> (++) x "?"`. ("Partial application" is in quotes, because the functions in Haskell always have just one argument, so application is no longer "partial"; in other languages (++) would be viewed as a function of two arguments, so when only one argument is applied, the function is deemed partially applied - in this sense it may be useful to view ("!"++) as a partially applied (++))

Your second example is a valid way of using (/), but if you use (/), it really is not a infix function anymore, so you get a error attempting to specify the first argument to (/) before the function name: `3(/)`. It still works if you remove the brackets: `(3 /)` is the same as `((/) 3)` or `(\x -> (/) 3 x)` or `(\x -> 3 / x)`

Comment: Partial applications and operator sections are related, but different concept. Better be careful, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner can you elaborate? I checked section of an infix operator http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator, and it starts with saying that section _is_ a partial application. What's the tiny difference then?

Comment: Not every partial application is a section. `map id` is a partial application (if you consider map a function with two parameters), but not an operator section.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner agreed on that. Let me see if my text isn't clear about this.